Simple tag synonym suggestions
Some tag synonym suggestions just don't require that much conversation to settle. That's why I prefer to consolidate simple synonym suggestions as answers to one big meta-question, which I'm starting here. This will also get more attention for all the simple little synonym creation tasks we have by facilitating readers' voting on them all at once. I'm basing this on a model question I've found useful on Cross Validated (CV), and proposing the same policy as I've discussed in a separate meta-question on CV...
Please upvote this question if you think it's a useful repository for simple synonym suggestions, and downvote if you prefer that all synonym suggestions be made as questions unto themselves. If you have specific comments or suggestions for this system, leave them as comments. Please only answer with new tag synonym suggestions, and upvote these if you think they should be made synonymous, or downvote them if you think the tags should not be synonyms. When answering, please indicate which tag should be the master tag and which should be the synonym that redirects to the master. Please also add information about the number of questions using each version of the tag, and briefly discuss any differences in the content of the tag wikis and excerpts.
As an initial recommendation subject to revision following the community's preferences, consider posting any complex synonym suggestions (e.g., involving more than 3 tags, requiring retagging effort, likely to deserve thorough discussion) as their own questions. This page will work best if suggestions here don't require more than a few comments to sort out before decisions are made. To reduce "clutter" and direct attention optimally, also consider flagging new synonym suggestion questions that are very simple as duplicates of this after they've been resolved. If it's not very simple (e.g.), don't call it a duplicate, as opinions will vary on where to draw the line between a simple suggestion for this page and a complex one that deserves its own. Also, feel free to delete your suggestions here after they've been implemented, and to suggest that others do the same, but do not consider deletion mandatory as an initial policy.

Master: hearing; Synonyms: audition,auditory
Questions tagged: 9, 7, & 1, respectively.
The one question tagged "auditory" is fairly new and could be retagged, which would zombify auditory and burninate it automatically six months later if I'm not mistaken.
hearing and audition have tag wikis; auditory does not.
hearing: For questions regarding the sensation (transduction) and perception of sound information by the brain in humans and animals.
audition: For questions pertaining to the sensation or perception of sound and its localization.
If localization is worth noting, this could be edited into the hearing wiki easily.

I don't know to which degree this is the scientifically established term, but I feel audition to be the least clear of other possible synonyms, 'auditory' and 'hearing' included.

I'd agree it's most obscure...Hadn't noticed [tag:hearing]! Will edit :)

A meta-tag synonym suggestion:
Master: tags; Synonym: tagging
Questions tagged: 42 & 1, respectively.
The one latter question is fairly old, but could be retagged, which would zombify tagging and burninate it automatically six months later if I'm not mistaken.
tags has a tag wiki; tagging does not. Seems an open-and-shut case with nothing to lose!
